# run PHPunit from cmd file

Tags: php, batch-file, phpunit

I had create a cmd file:

```
phpunit Test.php > myTest.txt
```

It work when i run is directly. But when exec with PHP code:

```
exec("cmd.cmd");
```

a file myTest.txt created, but it blank

Comment: It may be because it cannot find the file in the provided location. Try running the test with absolute path in the cmd file (for both txt and php file).

Comment: but the txt file was create, it mean the cmd file run. But "phpunit Test.php" not work. btw, it still work when i run cmd file directly... idk :(

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because phpUnit is not run when you call it via php (this could be due to security privileges).

Try

```
$output = '';
exec("cmd.cmd", $output);
echo $output;
```

And see what the execution actually returned, also you might need to specify a path since exec might run from the PHP execution path, not your PHP webroot where the file exists.